# Retargeting the foreign key in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

**tldr;**

In Rails, how do you set the target column of a foreign key to be a column other than its parent’s id?

**Efforts so far**

This feels like it should be a simple operation, but I’m having little success. I have a parent model, Order, which has many OrderItems, but I want the foreign key of OrderItems to reference a composite of Order’s reference1 and reference2 fields.

I’ve looked at a few paths:

**First try**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items,    foreign_key: :order_reference,
                            primary_key: :unique_reference
                            inverse_of: :order
  validates :reference1, uniqueness: { scope: :reference2 }
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order,    foreign_key: unique_reference,
                        primary_key: order_reference
                        inverse_of: :order_item
end
```

(Where I created a redundant-feeling unique_reference column, that we populated before creation with reference1+reference2, and gave OrderItem a corresponding order_reference column)

I tried a few variants of the above, but couldn’t persuade the OrderItem to accept unique_reference as the key. It managed to link records, but then when I called OrderItem#order_reference, instead of contents matching the corresponding Order#unique_reference field it would return a stringified version of its parent’s id.

**Second try**

I removed the unique_reference column from the Order class, replacing it with a method of the same name and a has_many block:

```
class Order
  has_many :order_items, -> (order) { where("order_items.order_reference = :unique_reference", unique_reference: order.unique_reference) }

  def unique_reference
    "#{reference1}#{reference2}"
  end
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, ->(item){ where("CONCAT(surfdome_archived_order.source, surfdome_archived_order.order_number) = surfdome_archived_order_items.archived_order_reference") }
end
```

This time, calling Order#order_items raises a SQL error:
Unknown column 'order_items.order_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `order_items`.* FROM `order_items` WHERE `order_items`.`order_id` = 1 AND (order_items.order_reference = 'ref1ref2')

Every SQL query I’ve thought to try has the same underlying problem - somewhere, Rails decides we’re still implicitly trying to key by order_id, and I can’t find a way to persuade it otherwise.

**Other options**

At the moment my options seem to be to use the [Composite Primary Keys gem](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys) or just ignoring Rails' built-in associations and hacking our own with db queries, but neither seems ideal - and it seems like Rails would surely have an option to switch foreign keys. But if so, where is it?

Thanks,

Sasha